# pyspark, logistic regression, how to get coefficient of respective features

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am new to `Spark`, my current version is 1.3.1. And I want to implement logistic regression with `PySpark`, so, I found this example from [Spark Python MLlib](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/mllib-linear-methods.html#logistic-regression)

```
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from numpy import array

# Load and parse the data
def parsePoint(line):
    values = [float(x) for x in line.split(' ')]
    return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/sample_svm_data.txt")
parsedData = data.map(parsePoint)

# Build the model
model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(parsedData)

# Evaluating the model on training data
labelsAndPreds = parsedData.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features)))
trainErr = labelsAndPreds.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(parsedData.count())
print("Training Error = " + str(trainErr))
```

And I found the attributes of `model` are:

```
In [21]: model.<TAB>
model.clearThreshold  model.predict         model.weights
model.intercept       model.setThreshold
```

How can I get the coefficients of logistic regression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you noticed the way to obtain the coefficients is by using [LogisticRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel)'s attributes.

> Parameters:
>
> **weights** – Weights computed for every feature.
>
> **intercept** – Intercept computed for this model. (Only used in Binary Logistic Regression. In Multinomial Logistic Regression, the
> intercepts will not be a single value, so the intercepts will be part
> of the weights.)
>
> **numFeatures** – the dimension of the features.
>
> **numClasses** – the number of possible outcomes for k classes classification problem in Multinomial Logistic Regression. By default,
> it is binary logistic regression so numClasses will be set to 2.

Don't forget that `hθ(x) = 1 / exp ^ -(θ0 + θ1 * x1 + ... + θn * xn)` where `θ0` represents the `intercept`, `[θ1,...,θn]` the `weights`, and the number of features is `n`.

#### Edit

As you can see this is the way how the prediction is done, you can check [LogisticRegressionModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/classification.html#LogisticRegressionModel.predict)'s source.

```
def predict(self, x):
    """
    Predict values for a single data point or an RDD of points
    using the model trained.
    """
    if isinstance(x, RDD):
        return x.map(lambda v: self.predict(v))

    x = _convert_to_vector(x)
    if self.numClasses == 2:
        margin = self.weights.dot(x) + self._intercept
        if margin > 0:
            prob = 1 / (1 + exp(-margin))
        else:
            exp_margin = exp(margin)
            prob = exp_margin / (1 + exp_margin)
        if self._threshold is None:
            return prob
        else:
            return 1 if prob > self._threshold else 0
    else:
        best_class = 0
        max_margin = 0.0
        if x.size + 1 == self._dataWithBiasSize:
            for i in range(0, self._numClasses - 1):
                margin = x.dot(self._weightsMatrix[i][0:x.size]) + \
                    self._weightsMatrix[i][x.size]
                if margin > max_margin:
                    max_margin = margin
                    best_class = i + 1
        else:
            for i in range(0, self._numClasses - 1):
                margin = x.dot(self._weightsMatrix[i])
                if margin > max_margin:
                    max_margin = margin
                    best_class = i + 1
        return best_class
```

Comment: thanks, but the coefficients of this demo are different with other python libs. Maybe the preprocessing method or the optimization method is different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
model.coefficients
```

and it works!

Documentation:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=coefficients#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.coefficients